# Como inserir quebra de linha em textarea em texto inserido via jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tenho uma textarea e gostaria de listar alguns itens nele um em cada linha.

Já estou inserindo o texto normalmente no textarea e separo os itens em vírgulas atualmente:

```
nomUgs = selUgs.join(", ");
```

No lugar dessa vírgula queria inserir quebra de linha. Tem como?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pode usar o `\n` para quebrar a linha.

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/Wm9um/

Por exemplo este código separa cada palavra em linha diferente:

```
var texto = 'Eu quero que este texto seja separado em muitas linhas!';
var linhas = texto.replace(/\s/g,'\n');
$('#testes').val(linhas);
```