# Quebra de linhas

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, firebase

Olá, criei um chat no meu site usando Firebase.
Mais não sei como fazer esta mensagem ser salva junto com a quebra de linhas.

[image: imagem 1]

Na imagem acima estou usando o textarea para escrever a mensagem.

Mais após enviar a mensagem ela não faz a quebra de linha como mostrado na foto abaixo.

[image: image 2]

Este é meu código que salva a mensagem no banco de dados do Firebase.

```
    $("#send_button").on('click', function () {

        var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        var displayName = user.displayName;
        var photoURL = user.photoURL;
        var mess = $("#msg").val();
        var date = formatAMPM(new Date());

        firebase.database().ref('chat/' + Date.now()).set({
            name: displayName,
            photo: photoURL,
            message: mess,
            date_and_time: date
        });
        var element = document.getElementById("scroll-chat");
        element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight;
        $("#msg").val("");

    });
```

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como inserir quebra de linha em textarea em texto inserido via jquery/javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21652/como-inserir-quebra-de-linha-em-textarea-em-texto-inserido-via-jquery-javascript)

Comment: Já tinha visto este exemplo mais não funcionou pra mim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que o problema esta na visualização. Textarea envia quebra de linha com `\n` e o html não o lê.

Tente alterar sua string para `<br />`, algo assim:

```
var str = 'olá\nEste é um teste de quebra de linha, teste1.';
str.replace(/\n/g,'<br />');
```

Comment: Consegui resolvendo o problema alterando a variável para var mess = $("#msg").val().replace(/\r?\n/g,'<br/>');